# Loosing sportsman rank?

Tags: gran-turismo-sport

Is there anyway to see a full list of all things that affect sportsman rank in Grand Turismo Sport?  It seems like simple things I'm doing are just destroying my rank and I'd prefer to not play in the gutter with people who have poor attitudes.

Comment: Haven't found a list, but basically any contact with other cars will drop your rating, even if you're innocent. *Don't do things that make you look bad.* 1-2 bumps per race should still be fine, if you're racing well.